# Tara in Panchakanya is Vali's wife or Brihaspati's wife?

Tags: vali, chandra, brihaspati, tara, sugriva

The shloka *Ahalya Draupadi Kunti Tara Mandodari tatha
panchakanya smare nityam mahapataka nashanam* lists 5 kanyas (some also list Sita instead on Kunti).

Here, Tara is Vali's wife (who later married Sugriva) or Brihaspati's wife (who with Chandra had Budha as son)?

Comment: Ahalya, Mandodari and Tara are from Ramayana. So Tara is wife of king Vali.

Comment: Sidenote - The concept of Panchakanya is not found in scriptures. It is a subhashita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Five Holy Virgins](http://www.manushi-india.org/pdfs_issues/PDF%20141/03%20panchakanya%204-12.pdf) by Pradip Bhattacharya, Tara in Panchkanya is Vali's wife:

> Tara,9 wife of Vali and daughter of
> the vanara physician Sushena, is the
> next kanya we meet in the Ramayana.

The end note further clarifies it:

> 9 Not to be confused with Tara, wife of
> Brihaspati, preceptor of the gods who
> elopes with his disciple Chandra, or with
> Taramati, wife of king Harishchandra in
> some Puranas and an example of a sati.