# Did Krishna actually call Draupdi as "Sakhi" ? Were Krishna and Draupdi friends?

Tags: mahabharata

I had watched Mahabharat on TV star plus. In the show , the Character of the Krishna used to call Draupdi "Sakhi" .And Draudpdi would call Krishna "Sakha" .

Were Krishna and Draupdi really friends ? How is this possible ? Draupdi was a normal woman .
Why will Krishna choose Draupdi as his friend ? There was nothing special about Draupdi

( Arjun was Krishna's friend as Arjun was avtar of Nara . And Nara and Narayan are eternal friends.)

Is such thing actually mentioned in Mahabharat ? I mean friendship between Krishna and Draupdi and Krishna calling Draupdi "Sakhi" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Krishna and Krishnaa (Draupadi) were friends:

> 53 कथं नु भार्या पार्थानां तव कृष्ण **सखी** विभॊ
>
> धृष्टद्युम्नस्य भगिनी सभां कृष्येत मादृशी
>
> O Krishna, how could one like me, the wife of Pritha's sons, the sister of Dhrishtadyumna, and **the friend of thee**, be dragged to the assembly! ~[Mahabharata: Vana Parva: Arjunabhigamana Parva](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03012.htm)

---

Draupdi was NOT a normal woman, she was an incarnation of Indra's wife Sachi which is described in [Is Draupadi a goddess?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10156/is-draupadi-a-goddess/22826#22826) post. She was Ayonija (a non​-uterine birth) and directly manifested from Yajna fire. Draupadi is one of the [Panchknyas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44612/12304), others being Ahalya, Kunti/Sita, Tara and Mandodari.

Comment: Can one say friendly sister?

Comment: Yeah but other than that is there mention anywhere else about Draupdi calling  Krishna her friend ? I don't think so.

Here also Krishna didn't call Draupdi his friend . It was Draupdi who called Krishna her friend. 
Also this is apparently the first time Krishna and Draupdi talked to each other. 

https://www.quora.com/When-did-Krishna-meet-Draupadi-for-the-first-time-How-many-times-did-they-meet-each-other-before-Krishna-was-invited-to-attend-Draupadi%E2%80%99s-Swayamvara-Sabha/answer/Lakshmi-Telidevara

How can a person who has met someone for the first time call him her friend ?

Comment: "Yeah but other than that is there mention anywhere else about Draupdi calling Krishna her friend ?" -- yes https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs05080.htm / https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05082.htm and at many other places but we hv to search which is bit difficult..

Comment: @YDS "Draupadi was not a normal woman" - why is this relevant to the answer? Are you implying that normal men and women can't be friends?

Comment: "Draupdi was a normal woman" - the Q says this that's why I added that in answer..i am NOT implying that normal men women can't be friends... @Ikshvaku

Comment: @YDS Ah ok, I didn't see that in the question, thanks for the clarification.