# Are there any documented cases of opposite-sex friendships in Hindu scripture?

Tags: vedas, puranas, smriti, itihasa, friendship

Are there any documented stories or cases of **non-sexual friendship** between men and women in Hindu scripture?

For reference, the Kama Sutra says sex with female friends is prohibited:
[image]

Then, here is how it defines friendship:

[image]

So, can we find any boy-girl friendships in the Puranas, Itihasas, Vedas, etc?

Comment: Krishna used to call Draupdi Sakhi. Both were perhaps friends .

Comment: @river Can you provide a verse where he says that?

Comment: There are multiple . One is [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/47996/23709)

Comment: @river Thanks. Can we find normal man-woman friend relationships that don't involve incarnation of gods?

Comment: Is the definition of friendship that you quoted from kamasutra or some other book ?

Comment: @river It's from the kama sutra.

Comment: @river but Draupadi and Krishna were relatives, were they not?

Comment: Kāmasūtra is not the correct text to look for this information. As its name suggests, it is purely for the purpose, art and techniques of carnal pleasure.
They are extremely few examples of male-female platonic friendships in itihāsa texts. Draupadī-Kr̥ṣṇa is the only example which comes in my mind as of now.

Comment: @AravindSuresh They became relatives after Draupadī's marriage to the Pāṇḍavas, but even before her marriage they were close friends.

Comment: The gopīs are also considered sakhis (friends) of Kr̥ṣṇa however that's a dodgy topic, because in some texts they seem to have sexual or romantic relations with Kr̥ṣṇa as well. So, I wouldn't consider that platonic friendship. It was rare to have platonic friendship among opposite genders in olden times, merely because of misogynism and patriarchy, women rarely interacted with men as equals unless in households as their mother, sisters or wives.  And those that did interact, often ended up developing romantic relationships. Platonic male-female friendships are rare cases.

Comment: ah, in case, it's not clear, platonic friendship means when the friends have no romantic or sexual relations or feelings for one another. Basically, it is a pure friendship.