# Having sex with which women is very big sin?

Tags: sin, sex

Having sex with which women is very big sin ?

Answer (score 3):

Having sex with [any women other than one's wife](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31763/23709) is sin.

But there are certain category of women with whom having sex is very big sin (equivalent to Brahmhatya)
I am mentioning them -

1. According to Manusmriti - Having sex with Guru's wife , sisters , unmarried maidens (or virgin women) , females of lowest castes , wife of a friend and wife of son are very big sin

> Manu Smriti 11.58. Carnal intercourse with sisters by the same mother,
> with (unmarried) maidens, with females of the lowest castes, with the
> wives of a friend, or of a son, they declare to be equal to the
> violation of a Guru’s bed

2. According to Kaamsutra (book of sex) , there are [some other women who are considered as unsexable](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/52400/are-there-any-documented-cases-of-opposite-sex-friendships-in-hindu-scripture) (i.e. one shouldn't even think of having sex with them which means having sex with them is very big sin ).
   Plus Kamasutra also prohibits having sex with any married women in general.
   (Chapter 5 verse 2)

[image]

3. According to Mahabharata having sex with someone's chaste wife is also a very big sin.

[Mahabharata Sambhav Parva](https://www.harekrsna.com/sun/editorials/mahabharata/mahabharata123.htm) -

> And, men, too, viol ting a chaste and loving wife who hath from her maidenhood observed the vow of purity, became guilty of the same sin.(i.e. killing of an embryo or greater sin than Brahmhatya)

4. There are some other categories of women too with whom having sex is very sin, they are mentioned [in this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/54094)

Comment: Not saying to cancel your rendezvous with nutcases and lepers or anything (hehe) however I happen to disagree w/ most religious views re treatment of women, treatment of LGBTQ people, views of sex as a sin etc. Not sure blindly following religious texts is ideal w/ respect to these particular issues cause there are unfortunately a lot of misunderstandings about these things. Lotsa interpolation as well. (Also btw not to be PC police here but I think “leper” is considered an offensive term. Like how you don’t say “dwarves” or “midget” you say “little people”)

Comment: But just to be clear there are tons of other things where I fully agree w/ the religious texts and I find what they have to say is magnificent and wonderful. (I sincerely think huge enormous interpolations and very very poor translations are to blame for most of the things where I disagree.)

Comment: @devibhakt      Kaam is considered as gateway to hell even in gita . Since almost all civilised culture consider having sex with mother and sister as very big sin , so there must be certain category of women who are unsexable. 
And if free sex is allowed , it will be very difficult to establish paternity and relationships will not exist. 
Even vedas in which chances of interpolation is very low talks about sex between husband and wife only , not free sex.

Comment: W/ religious texts I disagree w/ certain things, I totally agree w/ other things. Treatment of women, treatment of gay people, I couldn’t agree w/ what they say. W/ relationships & marriage, I also find I (partially) have some slightly different views. Women who grew up in Christian churches also don’t agree w/ church views of LGBTQ folks, gay people, marriage etc. Churches & priests in any religion forcing women to stay in horrible marriages even if husband is beating them, abusing them, doesn’t seem ok to me. Blind obedience to abusive elders/parents seems not ok. We can agree to disagree :)

Comment: @devibhakt one would agree with everything when understands the reasons for birth, the results of karma of many thousand previous lives and what one gets in this life. Some are born rich, some poor, some healthy, some with challenges, some tall, others dwarfs,... If one is leper, it's about one to experience it. There are numerous texts to show compassion towards those in difficulty(health or wealth). But there are also things which people are to experience.

Comment: @Kanthri What you are saying, I actually fully agree w/ that (the karma argument.) I think we could understand something happening due to karma while at the same time we calmly & respectfully have our own views and ideas of how we might live and treat people. For example I don’t think that sincerely genuinely psychologically (and spiritually) progressive and educated ppl will be racist, sexist, misogynistic, homophobic, animal-abusers, etc. Just my view. I think Hinduism is highest best knowledge in the world, I just think some interpolations and misunderstandings came in over centuries :)

Comment: @devibhakt "racist, sexist, misogynistic, homophobic, animal-abusers, etc." probably not the right words there. Interpolations may have taken place in some texts. But we see consistency on some of these across many texts. So, that theory is unlikely. Misunderstanding is also same. Compassion, care, support, etc. are the basics of one's conduct. The question we need to ask is why the scriptures say so. Then one will find the answer rather than ignoring it.

Comment: Having said all these, our dharma gives one the option to decide whatever one wants to decide! At end of Gita Krishna tells Arjuna that you do what you think is right!! That's the beauty. If one is feminist, one may ignore the statements which asks women to serve her husband; or one can think this is my duty, this is why I was born like this...and do it. If we want to challenge, we can challenge everything for argument sake, even the existence of paramatma.

Comment: @Kanthri I’m not trying to challenge for arguments sake. I just find I couldn’t make myself agree with some things written. Like I’m vegan and many of our religious texts say pashu-bali is good, hunting animals is ok, eating meat is acceptable for Kstriyas. I couldn’t make myself agree with such stuffs because goes against my personal morals. I really care about animals and I just can’t do those things, doesn’t seem like the right way to me. There are lots of things written in our religious texts that I do agree with, then there are some things I don’t agree. I think that’s ok :D

Comment: @Kanthri By the way I just saw that old post of yours about Daksh illicit relations w/ his daughter. I didn’t know about that ?! No wonder Sati was so angry

Comment: @devibhakt- who said LGBTQ people are moral and deserve same treatment as others ? they are born that way because of their perverted desires in previous births. we can and should show them compassion for being punished, just as we show compassion to dwarves/disabled/lepers, but we should never equate them same as regular people because that would mean they didn't do anything wrong earlier and that they are not being punished.

Comment: @mar Don’t know why I didn’t receive notification for your comment, is not showing up. I understand that what you’re saying is the stance of both Hinduism & the Christian church, especially right wing evangelicals, however I don’t see LGBTQ people that way. I sometimes wonder if there were numerous interpolations and misunderstandings from translations of religious text over centuries w/ respect to these things. I’m not sure. Anyway I think we may have such different views on this that we could perhaps agree to disagree ?

Comment: @mar However just want to reiterate, even though there are some things where I disagree with the texts (or the possible interpolations or misunderstandings or whatever) there are tons and tons of things in Hindu texts that I fully agree with. I think Hinduism is wonderful, I love it so much. And I think there’s room for different views in it, lots of discussion & debate. Like when I think of Vishnu bhakts arguing w/ Shiv bhakts, they are emotional and argue what they believe, and they have differing viewpoints. I think it’s ok to disagree some things, discuss them, have some debates on them :D